# Overflow: Hid Overflow: hidden is not working or the text is not respecting the max-height of the div?

Tags: html, css

I am making an alert configuration in the streamlabs OBS for the twitch, it is a bit alert in which the person can send a message that appears. However, when I used a max-height, ellipsis, and an overflow: hidden to control the size of the message that will appear in the text box and it doesn't overflow the created layout, however the text-overflow is not working, testing on some old bits that have a lot of text, they are limited to the text balloon, but burst at the bottom being cut off. Does anyone know why overflow: hidden is not working? And I didn't want to use a white-space: nowrap, because it would be just one line of text. Does anyone know how I would solve this?

This is how it looks in some who apparently don't even respect the padding in the ballon:
[image: This is how it looks in some who apparently don't even respect the padding in the ballon]

This is the correct way to stay, even if the message is large, but in the first image it is not:
[image: This is the correct way to stay, even if the message is large, but in the first image it is not]

**This is the code that streamlabs obs uses and what I modified in the css to have the balloon.**

```
<!-- alert image -->
<div id="alert-image-wrap">
  <div id="alert-image">{img}</div>
</div>

<!-- main alert box window -->
<div id="alert-text-wrap">

  <!-- alert text -->
  <div id="alert-text">

    <!-- alert message -->
    <!-- messageTemplate will be replaced with your message template -->
    <!-- for example : {name} is now following! or {name} donated {amount} -->

    <div id="alert-message">{messageTemplate}</div>
    <div id="alert-user-message">{userMessage}</div>

  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#alert-user-message{
  min-width: 48px;
  min-height: 32px;
  max-width: 605px;
  max-height: 158px;
  margin-top: -195px;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#alert-user-message:before{
  content:"\A";
  left: calc(50% - 2rem);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 2rem 2rem 2rem;
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
  position: fixed !important;
  margin-top: -35px;
}
```

If someone can get me out of this doubt, why these alerts occur, I would be very grateful. Thank you

Comment: can you change the pictures? looks like you're insulting people in portugese. Maybe you can ask the same question without using those images? or with modified images?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function toggleClass() {
    var element = document.getElementById("box");
    element.classList.toggle("full");
}
```

```css
 #box {
    height: 65px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    padding: 10px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 4;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
#box.full{
    height: unset;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita temporibus quam ex repudiandae, beatae
    doloremque harum, nesciunt nihil debitis a sit minus in, nulla necessitatibus veniam numquam. Voluptatibus,
    saepe impedit.
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="toggleClass()">Toggle</button>
```